# Returning a constexpr std::array

Tags: arrays, c++11

When I try to compile this class, the linker tells me that FooHandler ::getFoo is is not found for architecture x86_64.

```
enum class Foo {Bar};


class FooHandler {

public:

    constexpr std::array<Foo, 1> static getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    static constexpr std::array<Foo, 1> foo = { {Foo::Bar} };
};


int main() {
    FooHandler::getFoo();
}
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Bonus question:

Is there any way I can replace the `1` by a const value?

Comment: Works for me with [gcc](http://rextester.com/FFP70462) and [clang](http://rextester.com/EGX13182)

Comment: `Is there any way I can replace the 1 by a const value?` I'm not sure I understand this question. What do you feel `1` is - a variable value?

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Sorry for my ambiguous question, what I meant was whether it is possible to replace the 1 by some constexpr or something similar?

Comment: Well, [yes it is](http://rextester.com/TAPAZ62674). That was rather trivial to check, you could have done it yourself. It's possible I misunderstand the question again.

Comment: This is really strange:

Using Cross G++ Compiler on Mac OS X

Building target: Sandbox
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++  -o "Sandbox"  ./src/Sandbox.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "FooHandler::foo", referenced from:
      FooHandler::getFoo() in Sandbox.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Sandbox] Error 1